# How to dynamically set outline border on the matplotlib canvas?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt5

I have 9 figures in canvas drew by matplotlib on my PyQt5 GUI can be seen here:

[image: GUI]

Canvases are generated dynamically:

```
class Canvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(Figure(figsize=(5, 3)))
        self.setParent(parent)
        self.mpl_connect("button_press_event", self.on_press)

    def on_press(self, event):
        print(self, event)

canvas = Canvas()
ax = canvas.figure.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y_leak, '--rs', label='Y_leak')
ax.plot(x, y_lin, '-g*', label='Y_lin')
ax.plot(x, y_sat, ':bo', label='Y_sat')
ax.legend()
```

My question is how can set an outline border of canvas for each one of them when on_press event called, like this.:
[image: like this.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution from the Qt implementation is to use a flag that indicates whether the canvas was pressed or not and then using that information, paint the border override the paintEvent method.

```py
class Canvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(Figure(figsize=(5, 3)))
        self.setParent(parent)
        self.mpl_connect("button_press_event", self.on_press)
        self._draw_border = False

    def on_press(self, event):
        self._draw_border = True
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super().paintEvent(event)
        if self._draw_border:
            painter = QPainter(self)
            pen_width = 5
            painter.setPen(QPen(QColor("#00ff00"), 2 * pen_width))
            painter.drawRect(self.rect())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you always answer my questions. I appreciate it! It works but I just noticed that I forgot to mention how to remove this border too. Do you mind if I edit the question and ask it too?

Comment: @justRandomLearner If you want to remove the border then just do `self._draw_border = False`
        `self.update()` , please understand my answer and don't just copy code.

Comment: Sure, I am new at PyQt5 and trying to learn it for my future usage but since I didn't know how the .update() function works, I didn't understand it well. Much clear now.